# VBA function that takes a dynamic array and returns a dynamic array

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I have a list of numbers with duplicates in A1:A100. With the new dynamic array functions of Excel, we could write in Cell D1 `=UNIQUE(A1:A100)` to get a unique list.

Then, we could write in Cell E1 `=D1#+100` to get a dynamic list based on the values of Column D.

Now, I would like to write a VBA function `MYFUN` to achieve the same thing, such that we could write `=MYFUN(D1#)` in Cell F1 to get the same values as Column E.

Dose anyone know how to write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you want to do - there appears to be something missing.

However this will return what you have in column E when you enter the formula `=MYFUN(D1#)` in F1.

```vb
Function MYFUN(rng As Range) As Variant
    MYFUN = Evaluate(rng.Address & "+100")
End Function
```

Here's an alternative that doesn't use `Evaluate`.

```vb
Function MYFUN(rng As Range) As Variant
Dim arr As Variant
Dim idx As Long

    ReDim arr(1 To rng.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)
        
    For idx = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        arr(idx, 1) = rng.Cells(idx, 1) + 100
    Next idx
    
    MYFUN = arr
    
End Function
```

Comment: Good to know this solution... But I would expect a solution that iterates over cells rather than using directly `D1#` in the body of the VBA, because what I want to do is more complicated that `+100`.

Comment: I've added code that iterates  rather than using `Evaluate`. If that still isn't what you are looking for please explain further.